# Target of a servlet

Tags: http, servlets, frames

When I use frames, I can use TARGET in order to tell the servlet where to send the result. So I can have a navigation where I have a search engine and then tell the servlet to give the result of the search in the content space. But what if I simply don't use frames? How can I navigate the servlet to the "position" I want the result to be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By using Ajax to call the servlet.

Comment: Is there really no way to do it without any extra technology?

Comment: If your site is at all modern its going to be using some javascript, probably jquery anyway, so its not really extra technology.